# Drupal block display the HTML itself

Tags: drupal

I need to add script to the block body to display banner but drupal display the script itself in the site for example it returns :

script  type='text/javascript' src=' /....../...'

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable PHP code in Drupal 7 Blocks.

- Access your website's admin panel, and log in to your Drupal site.
- Click on 'Modules'. Scroll down until you find **PHP filter**. It's a built-in module in Drupal 7.
- Click on "Structure" then click "Blocks." Click "Add New Block" or click "Edit" next to the block with which you want to use PHP code.
- Scroll down beneath the "Block Body" section. Click on "Text Input." Select "PHP Code." This allows you to use PHP in the block's body.
- Now you can add any HTML code to your block, and it will display the result as content.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it also gives the same result

Comment: can you give a fiddle of the code u entered in the block?

Comment: its a script tag only  and it works in another drupal site, the question is why it is working in one and returns the script tag itself in the other one?!

Answer (score 0):

Enabling php filter (as suggested below) won't help with inserting javascripts, only php code.

Are you using the Full HTML text format? If you are using a wysiwyg editor, be sure that you are editing the source of the content.

**Update**

A workaround could be to use the 'Code per node' module:

https://drupal.org/project/cpn

That module adds extra fields to the Visibility settings. These fields are then used to input some extra CSS or javascripts.

Comment: If you go to 'Configuration -> Content Authoring -> Text formats -> Full HTML', is the 'Limit allowed HTML tags' field checked?

Comment: I just thought of a workaround that might work for you, updated my answer :-)